# Ruby on rails ActiveRecord Relation not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an issue where my ActiveRecord::Relation isn't working I have 3 Db's Users,Games,Achievements The relation defined between them is such

Users

```
has_many :games
```

Games

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :achievements
```

Achievements

```
belongs_to :game
```

The problem is when i try to call

```
Game.where(:appid => game["appid"]).achievements.new
```

it gives me and error saying that

```
undefined method `achievements' for #<Game::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x730f9f8>
```

I am running on Ruby on Rails 4.1.8 and I have no clue why this is happening (I do have the belongs_to :game,index: true column in my Achievements table I can't think of why its not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an association here:

```
 Game.where(:appid => game["appid"])
```

... this is realized as an array of objects (even if the sql returns no records, then it is still an array, although it is empty).

You need to select one of them ... probably the first, like this:

```
 Game.where(:appid => game["appid"]).first.achievements.new
```

Or you can run through the values:

```
 Game.where(:appid => game["appid"]).each { |game| game.achievements.new }
```

or some such.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that all query's always come back as an array , thanks the problem is fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should select one model

```
Game.where(:appid => game["appid"]).first
```

and then get relational models

```
.achievements.new
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the exception.  #where returns an ActiveRecord_Relation, not a Game, even if there is only one Game in the relation.  So you really have an enumerable. i.e:

```
puts Game.where(:appid => game["appid"]).first.achievements.new
```

If you just want the first game that meets the criteria, you can use find_by

```
Game.find_by(:appid => game["appid"])
```

but I am not sure that's what you are looking for